# How to restore a whole OS from TSM image backup?

Tags: backup, ibm-unix-system-services

With a:

dsmc b image FSNAMEHERE

I can back up all the filesystem in a machine. But how can I restore it?

Boot off a liveCD, install TSM client somehow, then restore image backup to local disk? OS is a redhat.

Comment: Unless told otherwise by TSM folks, whole OS restore usually go this way: install minimal OS (same version), install backup/restore software (e.g. TSM), full restore, reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://relax-and-recover.org/

install it on the server you want to backup, then run it, it creates an ISO file.

with that ISO file you can boot up and restore it.

if it has problems with the restore, use the TSM client on it.